# Handling per-primitive normals when there are less vertices than primitives in OpenGL4.5

Tags: opengl, graphics

I've had a bit of trouble coming up with a solution for passing the correct normals to a fragment shader in **OpenGL** 4.5 for each of the triangle primitives to be able to use per triangle normals while doing indexed triangle rendering. (I want to use an IBO)

My current solution that works for some of models is to basically set the first vertex of each primitive to be the provoking vertex and have the primitive's normal be counted as the normal from the provoking vertex. (Of course adding the flat modifier to the normal attribute in the shaders)

This should work for most models but I've realized that it just doesn't work when there are more triangle primitives than vertices in a model. The simplest example I can come up with is a triangular bipyramid.

Is there a typical way this is done in industry for **OpenGL**? In industry are models just so large that per vertex normals are easier to implement and look better?

Comment: Typical practice is to duplicate the vertex per face. I see that you found a clever way to reduce the amount of duplication, which is also fine.

Comment: and yes, per-vertex normals are also common, but that's a question of art style, not engineering

Comment: "*Is there a typical way this is done in industry for OpenGL?*" Well, the "industry" doesn't really use per-primitive normals, so it's kind of an irrelevant thing there. In the rare cases where they do get used, it tends to depend on the nature of the geometry in question, memory vs. performance tradeoffs, asset conditioning, etc. There's no simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in the comments, "in the industry" one would often duplicate vertices that have discontinuous normals. This is unavoidable when only parts of your geometry are flat shaded and parts are smooth, or there are creases in it.

If your geometry is entirely flat shaded, an alternative thing you can do is to use the `gl_PrimitiveID` to fetch the per-primitive normal from an SSBO in the fragment shader:

```
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer NormalsBuffer {
    vec4 NORMALS[];
};

void main() {
    vec3 normal = NORMALS[gl_PrimitiveID].xyz;
    // ...
}
```

You can also use the `unpackSnorm2x16` or similar functions to read normals stored in smaller datatypes and thus reduce the bandwidth, much like with vertex array attributes.