# Can the provoking vertex be used for face varying normal/flat shading?

Tags: opengl, directx, vulkan

I am trying to optimize the amount of data sent to the GPU when 3D models rendered with a real-time API such as OpenGL or Vulkan require a normal per face (as opposed to a normal per vertex for smooth shading).

The brute force approach consists of duplicating the triangle (the primitive being used in this case) vertices so that, essentially each triangle in the description of a given mesh is unique. So in addition to the vertices position, you also attach the face normal. In this approach, not only you need to duplicate the vertices, but you also carry 3 normals instead of one. That's a lot of data for something rather trivial (flat shading).

[image]

I read somewhere about the provoking vertex and flat shading interpolation mode. So it seems that in that approach, I could avoid duplicating the vertices and just set the index vertex buffer indices in such a way that each triangle starts on the vertex to which the face normal would be attached.

However, I need clarification about how you would prepare the model for the GPU when this approach is used. Imagine a fan of triangles (a cone, for instance) where all the triangles share one vertex. The face vertex normals should be attached to the remaining vertices. Explained this seems logical, but I need to figure out how you can develop a generic algorithm that would know to which vertex in the model you need to attach the face vertex normal and how to build in the index array from there.

1. is provoking vertex the right approach to reduce the amount of data in the case of flat shading? And you would still need to attach 1 normal per vertex (and some of these normals might not be used during shading), but at least you would have a more compact vertex array.
2. is there a generic algorithm to prepare the vertex and index buffer for flat shading (face varying normal)? Can you describe this generic algo? Or point me to an example? (source code)
3. If not, how would you do it otherwise (besides the brute force approach?).

### edit:

I found this post which askes more  or less something similar/related:
[Handling per-primitive normals when there are less vertices than primitives in OpenGL4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239869/handling-per-primitive-normals-when-there-are-less-vertices-than-primitives-in-o?rq=2)

It's a recent question, and the answer is interesting but I am yet to believe that there could a generic solution to this problem (i can't use primitiveId in my case anyway). For example:

When you need to assign a vertex normal to a triangle you could:

1. check whether this normal has already been assigned to one of the vertices that make up the current triangle. If so use that vertex as the provoking vertex.
2. if not look whether there's a free vertex in the triangle that hasn't got a normal attach to it yet.

   - if yes, attach the normal to it, and set that vertex as the provoking vertex.
   - if not, then there would be a problem).

And yes, as pointed out in the comment, 2.b would definitely happen. Imagine 2 cones mirroring each other and sharing the same vertices in the middle. There would be more faces in this mesh than vertices.

As pointed in the comment, I am looking for a solution that does not use primitiveID and a buffer (one of the requirements of the problem being solved in my case). So I am interested to see if another "generic" algorithm exists for that sort of optimization.

Comment: FYI: The provoking vertex conventions for OpenGL and D3D/Vulkan are different.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes thank you) but the principle would be the same).

Comment: So what exactly is that you're asking that that other question doesn't answer? It's rather normal to have more triangles than vertices if your mesh represents a manifold, so 2.b will happen almost always. Why is that that you cannot use gl_PrimitiveId? Do you realize that having a separate buffer for normals will require even less data than provoking-vertex solutions? What makes you think that implementing this allocation algorithm (and handling 2.b correctly) would be simpler than having a separate buffer?

Comment: @yakov galka. I can't get into the details but I can't use primitiveID. That's a requirement of the problem i need to solve and therefore using a buffer to store the normal is not a solution I can use. So my question is different in the sense that I am interested to know if there's "another" generic algorithm to deal with that kind of optimization.